# Confusion on correct state space differential equations for LR circuit

Tags: inductor, state-space

For the circuit shown below, I have been deriving state space equation considering inductor current I1 and I2 as states, Vi, Ri and R as inputs (input supply and load resistance are variable inputs). Output of the system is V2 voltage across the load resistance.

X = [I1 I2]

U = [Vi Ri R]

Y = [V2]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYBwdR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is my derivation:[image: Differential equations for I1 and I2]

As per the circuit, if I apply my load (R) as a very high value from time 0, both the inductors should carry same current (I1 = I2), and they should charge to the steady state current in some time (as inductor opposes sudden change in currents).

But, as per the state space differential equation, if R is a very high value, I would be getting a high dI/dt, which is an unexpected behavior of the inductor. Also, the two currents don't come out to be same in this scenario as per the state space model.

Looking out for a justification or a rectification here! I have been successfully using state space even for complex circuits, but it's failing for this simple case as this!!

Comment: Rather than mess with this for you (I'm lazy today), why not watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RG_tdz1VzwY). He moves fast so doesn't waste your time and gets right to a formulaic approach that can't fail. Just works. Your transfer function also is exactly as he solves, except yours is a degree less on the numerator and a degree less on the denominator. So even easier and less to write down. Your transfer function is trivial to write out, too:

Comment: $$\begin{align*}&&G_s&=A\frac1{1+Q\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}+\frac{\omega_{_0}}{s}\right)}\\\\\text{where: }&&\omega_{_0}&=\sqrt{\frac{R_i\,R}{L_1\,L_2}}\\\\&&Q&=\frac{\sqrt{R_i\,R\,L_1\,L_2}}{L_1\,R+L_2\,R_i+L_2\,R}\\\\&&A&=\frac{R\,L_2}{L_1\,R+L_2\,R_i+L_2\,R}\end{align*}$$May need some manipulation, of course. But left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

A relevant part of your state space model matches mine:

[image]

Here, for the sake of simplicity (with no loss), I took just a subset of your model, resulting in just one input \$V_i\$ and the output being the state variables themselves (currents in inductors):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 \dot{I_1} \\
 \dot{I_2} 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 -\frac{(R+R_i)}{L_1} & \frac{R}{L_1} \\
 \frac{R}{L_2} & -\frac{R}{L_2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 I_1 \\
 I_2
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{1}{L_1}  \\
 0  
\end{bmatrix}V_i \qquad{[1]}$$

With a corresponding simulator diagram:

[image]

Considering zero initial conditions (\$I_1(0) = I_2(0) = 0 A\$) and the following values for the components:

$$
\begin{aligned}
 &R_i = 6 \Omega \\
 &R = 120 \Omega  \\
 &L_1=1\mu H \\
 &L_2=100\mu H 
\end{aligned}
$$

A step response from that system (with \$V_i=12V\$) is shown below:

[image]

**Conclusions:**

**1.** For the steady state condition, its enough to make the \$\frac{dI_2}{dt}|_{t\to \infty}=0\$ in \$[1]\$, resulting in \$I_1(\infty)=I_2(\infty)\$. In a similar manner, \$\frac{dI_1}{dt}|_{t\to \infty}=0\$ leads to \$I_1(\infty)=I_2(\infty)=\frac{V_i}{R_i}=2A\$, as expected (inductor is a "short-circuit" for DC). So, there are no discrepancies between the circuit and the model.

**2.** Since that \$I_1(0)=I_2(0)=0A\$, from \$[1]\$ it's possible to get \$\frac{dI_1}{dt}|_{t=0_+}= \frac{V_i}{L_1}=12000000A/s\$ and \$\frac{dI_2}{dt}|_{t=0_+} = 0A/s\$, So, your statement "*...I would be getting a high dI/dt, which is an unexpected behavior of the inductor.*" does not proceed. The inductor current cannot jump immediately to another value, but its derivative can (if necessary) to assume a high value. Note, in above graphs, the magnifying glass detailing what happens at an instant closer to \$t=0\$. Apart from this moment, both currents remain very close, with minor dependence on whether the \$R\$ value is high or not.

Comment: Hi Dirceu, but in your state space matrices, R looks like assumed to be a constant, as it's inside the A matrix of AX + BU. For my purpose, I am assuming that R, i.e., the load, is variable and is an input to the system. So essentially, shouldn't it be a part of the U matrix?

Comment: As I mentioned in the text, my simplification was adopted for the discussion about the behavior of current derivatives at t= 0 and in steady state, which is the heart of your question. If R is changed, it would be enough to run a new simulation.

Comment: Hi Direcu, I would want to vary R like a switching load in the same simulation, not across different simulations

Comment: I though my conclusions at the end of my answer could be useful to you (mainly about the derivatives of currents). At this moment, I have no additional time to continue from that.

Comment: One other thing: If you decide to put R as an input and keep your choice of state variables as I1 and I2, this may end up leading to multiplications between inputs and state variables not being possible to put in the format Ax+Bu. This appears in nonlinear systems, which often must be linearized around an operating point.